# Who should the moderators be?

Tags: discussion, 7-questions, moderators

The issue of holding fair elections is largely technical. The long-term solution will likely come from [Stack Exchange management]. Still, bring up these issues in meta. There is a lot of room for innovation. Discussing the criteria of a great moderator is important and picking out potential candidates is a great way to introduce outstanding contributors to your community. And [management] are completely open to appointing temporary Moderators when someone’s contribution makes them a standout choice for your community’s [human exception handler](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/).

For more detail see: [Moderator Pro Tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/) and [Stack Exchange Moderator Elections Begin](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/stack-exchange-moderator-elections-begin/)

Comment: As far as I recall, moderators pro tempore are not voted from the community, but they are chosen among the most active users, with the higher reputation. Stack Exchange will contact those users, and see who is interested to be appointed moderator pro tempore.

Comment: @kiamlaluno We value community's input into who the best choices would be.

Comment: @kiamlaluno My understanding is that reputation is much less of a factor than activity, which in itself is much less of a factor than maturity.

Comment: @corsiKa: I would hope that's the case. I don't think moderation responsibilities should bestowed on whoever happens to stake out here for a week or two, answering a heap of questions in one initial burst of enthusiasm.

Comment: @MετάEd My choice! He seems just,wise and gentleman! :0)

Answer (score 33):

I think ЯegDwight ought to be our first moderator here, at least *pro tem*. He's the one who created the original proposal, and he has demonstrated his mad mod skills on EL&U and GL&U. I have a lot of respect for him. He has a vision of what this site ought to be like and I think it is a good one.

Comment: I definitely agree. He's a great mod on ELU, and I respect him very highly.

Comment: I agree he is very helpful, and worth noting.

Comment: A gentleman of great principle and great tact. If he were willing to undertake it, we could not do better; even if his obligations to ELU preclude his actually acting as a moderator, he should be conceded the privileges and designated *moderator honoris causa* for his services to this site.

Comment: If these people tried the moderation I promise you bother them as much as I can! :))

Comment: @user37, albeit your comment is now deleted, I like to point out that Reg is not my choiche, but he has done an excellent work on EL&U. If EL&U is what it is--e.g., one of the better English site on Internet--, we must be grateful to him.

Answer (score 19):

I think @J.R. ought to be our first moderator here. He has largely contributed many answers to 
[meta.english.SE](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/users/18220/j-r?tab=answers) and has shown advanced expertise in defining the community policy.

Comment: @J.R.  Here is my +1 for you. I believe you will do a great job as a moderator here.

Comment: Whatever you put in your original nomination, I definitely support the idea of J.R. as a mod. He's participated both on ELU and ELL, including creating posts on Meta.ELL which could become canonical.

Comment: J.R. ran for mod on EL&U, and represented himself well. I think he would be a great mod here.

Comment: I heartily endorse this nomination; I've been paying attention since it went up and have been consistently impressed with J.R.'s temperate and sensible answers.

Answer (score 13):

I hope that in selecting the protemporals SE will consider including representatives of all three of the major constituencies here:

- the English-language 'experts', who provide most of the answers and inevitably get the most reputation;
- the non-native-speaker questioners, who more than make up for any linguistic deficiency by an acute (sometimes painful!) understanding of the real needs of our audience;
- the teachers of English, who know better than any of us how the needs are best addressed.

Comment: Yes: the experts that we want to attract to ELL are experts in *teaching*.

Comment: Mods need not be content experts, rather they need to be comfortable with the topic and should be good at dealing with people.

Comment: I like your proposal. I think diversity is somewhat important. Diversity can be as how you define it: experts, non-experts, good teachers (who are not necessarily English experts), native/non-native speakers.  It can also include folks from different time zones and their technical knowledge.

Answer (score 8):

Having spoken with her in chat and read her Meta questions, I would like to nominate [WendiKidd](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/289/wendikidd) as one of the moderators. She has made a distinct effort both to answer users' questions and try to make the site successful. Some of her Meta posts have aimed to:

- Figure out the [audience](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172/what-is-our-expert-self-serving-self-sustaining-audience/224#224) of the site
- Make the site [more welcoming](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/330/wait-a-few-minutes-before-closing-new-users-questions) for new users
- Understand better herself [how Beta works](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215/lack-of-accepted-answers)

In addition, she is active in chat, which shows a willingness to build and foster the sense of community here.

Comment: Thank you very much for the nomination! I humbly accept and would be very glad to help moderate the site as we get our footing in beta and go forward to make ELL the best it can be!

Comment: But @WendiKidd mind it, it is a lot of pressure to deal with ;)

Answer (score 5):

A moderator should be someone that has proven themselves worthy of being a moderator. They may not necessarily have much rep, however their answers should be of reasonable quality.

They should be able to take, give and request feedback on questions and answers via comments, and should be able to communicate with the entire community.

Comment: Why. The. Down. Votes.

Comment: Me and you both... :(

Comment: I have no idea why people would disagree with this. Maybe it is too generic for their liking?

Comment: @Kit I think it had something to do with the edit I unedited out ;)

Answer (score -1):

I'm throwing my hat into the ring.

[image: profile for Deco at English Language Learners, Q&A for speakers of other languages learning English]

[profile for Deco on Stack Exchange, a network of free, community-driven Q&A sites http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/1018203.png](http://stackexchange.com/users/1018203)

I'm familiar with the workings of SE sites and have been around SE for a little while now. I would like to see this community grow and ELL become the canonical resource for people who are learning English.

I'm also on an Australian Timezone (GMT+10 [AEST]) which means I am active when those who are around the Atlantic are usually asleep, so there would always be someone floating around.

If you'd like to know more feel free to ping me in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7227/english-language-learners) or ask in a comment.

Answer (score -6):

I would like to nominate myself for moderator. I was a little late in commiting to the Area 51 proposal, and I wasn't able to promote the sight, as I would have liked. However I believe I am a good responsible user, who has what is best for the community in mind. I don't have the most reputation on the site, however I have enough to show I am active. I also believe I have done a good job, in helping to moderate the site with my somewhat-limited powers.

Thank you for your consideration,

Mark Robinson [Main](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/67/mark-robinson), [Meta](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/users/67/mark-robinson)

Comment: Hi Mark! I'm sorry to see your nomination has been so downvoted. I'm puzzled by that, but I wonder if it is because you don't have much rep here. Are you familiar with how SE works? Do you have lots of rep on a different site? You sound like a nice, level-headed person. DO you have experience moderating?

Comment: @Mark: Possibly some or all of those downvotes are because all you have in you profile is *"**Delete Me!**"*. Also, apparently you haven't been here for almost a month, so possibly you'll never read this comment anyway.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I guess it was the opposite. First, this post got 12 downvotes, zero comments. Then Mark decided to leave. It's a bit childish (not a quality of a mod), but it tells alot about the community as well: **none of us** cared to tell Mark that user rep is not sufficient for being a mod. Instead, someone who wants to be a mod, should participate in Meta and strive to do a janitor work: cleaning, flagging, editing, etc.